# show attribute value in admin magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I am new in magento.

I added an extra field in `sales_flat_order` table i.e.,`order_campaign_params`
When a customer completed its order, data is inserting into this table.
Now i want to show this attribute value in admin. 
I added an extra column in admin i.e., `Order Utm Source` but data is not showing. 
Please tell me how to show the attribute value in admin.
Please see the code for adding column

```
 $this->addColumn('order_campaign_params', array(
           'header' => Mage::helper('orderreport')->__('Order Utm Source'),
           'index' => 'order_campaign_params',
           'filter_index'=>'customer_entity.order_campaign_params',
           'width' => '70px',
       ));
```

But how to show data of that field, Please explain.

Please see the structure:

customer_entity_varchar table

```
value_id entity_type_id  attribute_id  entity_id    value 
 136977             1          5        43120     Sanghamitra
 136978             1          7        43120     samal
 136979             1          12       43120     0860142023b7a810ce66a21b68
 136980             1          174      43120     data(order_compaign_params)
 136981             1          3        43120     Kalazone.in
```

Thanks

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647460/add-and-show-new-column-in-sales-flat-order-and-show-this-at-order-grid-in-magen

Comment: It also given to add an extra column which i already did it but it is not showing the value of that field

Comment: see the answer, it says about the `sales/order_grid` collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sales order grid is build from `sales_flat_order_grid` table. The column `order_campaign_params` exists in `sales_flat_order` table and not `sales_flat_order_grid` table.

So you need to MySQL join with `sales_flat_order_grid` table `sales_flat_order` table like below:

```
$select = $collection->getSelect();
$select->joinLeft(array('order' => Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',
array('order_campaign_params' => 'order_campaign_params'));
$select->joinLeft(array('custeav' => 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'custeav.attribute_id=main_table.order_campaign_params', array('*'));
```

The `order_campaign_params` column will now be displayed in the grid.

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i am adding the above lines it shows error 
There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: ok issue is solved.........would you please help me to get attribute value from customer_entity_varchar table????

Comment: I just comment this line from the page
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => array('payment_success','payment_success_cod','stitching','printed','processing','partial_dispatch','complete ','delivered ','rto_received','refunded','rto')));

Comment: please help me to get attribute value from customer_entity_varchar table.

Comment: ok. is `order_campaign_params` a customer_attribute .? and which value are you storing in the `sales_flat_order` table.?

Comment: add this join `$select->joinLeft(array('custeav' => 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'custeav.attribute_id=main_table.order_campaign_params',
                array('*'));`

Comment: Note. If you are storing value in the `order_campaign_params` then join using `value` column instead of `attribute_id`

Comment: you need to add this join on the main collection from where sales_order collection is rendered

Comment: It shows the same error
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.order_campaign_params' in 'on clause'

Comment: i dnt knw ur db structure. cant help u further

Comment: please follow this link i used this to insert data in both tables hope it  helps you and you can help me
https://github.com/RobM84/Magento-Robm-Tracking

Comment: Hi i updated the structure of Customer_entity varchar table in my question.please see above thanks